# Using AngularJS to display form validation errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my current html code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.inputName.$invalid && !form.inputName.$pristine }">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><font color='RED'>* </font>Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter in a name." required />
        <p ng-show="form.form.$invalid && !form.form.$pristine" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this works well for fields that are mandatory for any case.

However, let's say the user could pick a tab like Hair Style and had to describe the color field and the length field. If these fields are blank, then display a small message (like ng-show). So based on whatever tab the user selects, if the proper information for that tab is not inputted, the user should see an error. How would I use angular to display that?

Eg. Controller code...

```
$scope.someButtonPressed = function() {
    if ($scope.color == "") {
        // display ng-show for color
        // input field should have a red border to it
    }
}
```

Here is where I got my html error validation code from: http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation which has detailed explanation and an example.

Also this [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) is must a read!!

If you want to make border color for a compulsory field then refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pg0s96tp/5/). 
You could use `ng-invalid` class for `ng-required` fields